# How to add preinstalled packages to the final image

Tags: openwrt

I got the source, successfully configured and built an image. I don't understand though how to add a preinstalled package to the result image. What I mean is for example I'd like to add vsftpd to the image. Yes, I can generate the image and after installing it to the target device or a virtual machine execute opkg install vsftpd but I want to avoid it and have it preinstalled and properly configured. How can I do that? Can somebody give a step by step instructions, I'm rather new to Linux in general and sometimes it's difficult to understand short hints.

Answer (score 2):

There is a good guide [here](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-developer/build.a.package).

A few things will change for you:

Enter the commands:

```
./scripts/feeds install -a -p package/feeds/packages/vsftpd
```

Then

```
./scripts/feeds update
make defconfig
make package/symlinks
make menuconfig
```

Then go to "Network"->"File Transfer" and mark vsftpd.

The rest of the steps should be the same as in the link above.